# Installation error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED, Looked in Logcat for Android Studio but still cant work out the issue?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to run my code but cannot sort the issue out, I have followed all other suggestions similar to this question but still cant sort out the issue. If anyone has suggestions below it would be appreciated. [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9IXW.jpg)

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <activity android:name=".CreateMain" />
            <activity android:name=".ViewActivity" />
            <activity android:name=".EditMain"/>
            <activity android:name=".DeleteActivity"/>
            <activity android:name=".MoveActivity" />
            <activity
                android:name=".SearchActivity"
                android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        />
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your app manifest file.. Can you add the manifest file in your question? Check your package name. It should not contain capital letters (eg. Com.App should be com.app).